I was stuck at the step "Create collection hello_milvus when trying to test out the Integration between Amazon Serverless MSK and Milvus on EKS
I am having trouble setting up Crossplane to deploy a distributed Milvus and serverless MSK cluster. Both deployments appear to be successful. I am using the example script from https://github.com/milvus-io/pymilvus/blob/master/examples/hello_milvus.py to test the setup, and it runs through to the end without issues.
However, when I try to test the integration, the process gets stuck at the step "Create collection hello_milvus". All pods are in the ready state. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can proceed or how to debug this issue?
The config in values.yaml looks like this
  externalKafka:
    enabled: true
    brokerList: boot-uw2boktt.c3.kafka-serverless.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:9098
    securityProtocol: SASL_SSL
    sasl:
      mechanisms: OAUTHBEARER

